# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website.com/ajaxrequest' from origin '<origin>' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to fetch some json response from my website through ajax but in console panel it keeps throwing this error.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://website.com/ajaxrequest' from origin 'chrome-extension://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here's my manifest

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

"manifest_version": 2,

"version": "1.1",
"short_name": "TestApp",
"name": "My Test App",
"icons": {"128":"logo.png"},
"description": "some short desc",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "XYZ",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
},

"permissions": ["https://wwww.website.com/*", "http://localhost/"],
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["jquery.min.js","scripts.js"],
    "matches": ["https://wwww.website.com/*"]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey. My code was right. Its just that I had to close my browser (all windows) and run it again. it seems to has fixed the problem. cheers!